# Returning a var from inside 2 functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, return

Basically I need to to return a variable from inside of a function using an ajax call.

Like so:

```
function returnStuff(){
  $.ajax({
    //do stuff
  }).done(function(response){
    return response;
  })
return response;
}
```

I can't just use a variable in the done function and return that because the function will just return the undefined variable before the call completes.

Is there any way that I can return a variable through 2 layers of functions or is there a way that I can wait to return until the call is complete?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 2):

No. You cannot synchronously wait/block in JavaScript. Best you can do is something like this:

```
function returnStuff(){
  return $.ajax({
    //do stuff
  }).done(function(response){
    // handle some stuff
  });
}

returnStuff().done(function() {
    // add a 2nd event handler (called after the one above)
});
```

You have to rearchitect your code to not depend on getting a result back immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery ajax async option. This will make the request blocking instead of asynchronous - note this can cause the UI to lock up while the request is happening, so I agree with Mark that you should change your code architecture to not require setting async false, however this does answer your question.

```
function returnStuff(){
    var ret;
    $.ajax({
       async: false,
       //do stuff,
       success: function(response) {
         ret = response;
       }
     });
     return ret;
}
```

Please note there is a really good write-up explaining why you should not do this here: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call#answer-14220323)

Comment: Thanks Sam, you're right - copy / paste and not checking fail on my part. Edited and fixed.

Comment: It's also deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. But I'm curious how this was implemented... as an infinite busy loop I imagine?